# Ejecutar un comando CMD con privilegios de administrador desde Java

Tags: java, cmd

Para un proyecto final, necesito crear un hotspot propio, usando una aplicación de Java desarrollada por mí, pero para ejecutar el comando CMD necesito privilegios de administrador, pero como podría hacerlo desde Java

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando para ejecutar los comandos de CMD

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Process proceso = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=miHotspot key=12345678");
            InputStream inputstream = proceso.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bf = new BufferedInputStream(inputstream);
            byte[] contents = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead = 0;
            String cmdContent="";
            while ((bytesRead = bf.read(contents)) != -1) {                
                cmdContent += new String(contents, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            System.out.println(cmdContent);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Este es el resultado que obtengo al ejecutarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías crear un acceso directo con privilegios de administrador, el acceso sería algo así:

```
correrá en el cmd /c Rundll32.exe Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState
```

Y tu código de java podría ejecutar el acceso directo como:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("cmd /c start \"\" \"accesoDirectoCreado.lnk\"")
```

Para que te ejecute como administrador, revisa dando click derecho sobre el acceso directo -> propiedades > avanzado > ejecutar como administrador (colocar aquí el check).

Otra opción sería un poco más sencilla de implementar, dependerá de tu criterio usar la una u otra (si tu S.O es en inglés colocar Administrator, si es español colocar Administrador):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("runas /profile /user:Administrator \"cmd.exe /c Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"cmd.exe /C start runas /user:DESKTOP-Q37KR20\\salud \"cmd taskkill /F /IM SESHI.exe /T\""
```

yo tengo este y abre la ventana del cmd pero te pide contraseña para abrir otra ventana CMD. En este caso salud es mi usuario [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el DESKTOP-Q37KR20 es el nombre de mi dispositivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando pongo la clave abre otro CMD pero sin permisos de administrador.

se que donde dice Salud iria el usuario administrador o administrator pero también pediría clave.

Tambien puedes usarlo asi

> runas /env /user:%USERNAME% "cmd taskkill /f /im SESHI /T"

donde /env hace que no pongas el Nombre del Dispostivo en este caso el mio es :DESKTOP-Q37KR20 y la variable %USERNAME% te da el nombre del usario que este en ese momento abierto en este caso es Salud.

haber si alguien mas puede ayudar para poder abrir una ventana CMD como Administrador sin serlo (el click derecho y correr como administrador ) y que a su vez se le pase el comando que quieras ejecutar.

en este caso yo quiero ejecutar este comando taskkill /F /IM SESHI.exe /T cuando se abra la otra ventana cmd pero en su lugar me lo pone como titulo de ventana
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y pues se queda  esperando el comando

Comment: con la novedad que ya no ocupo abrir un  CMD como administrador para ejecutar la instruccion TASKKILL.

ya que la idea era. con CMD descargar el programa de un servidor. luego cerrar el programa que esta abierto en este momento y despues ejecutar otro CMD para que comience con la instalacion de la actualizacion del programa.

y lo que hice fue colocar un Hilo nuevo al segundo CMD que es el que abre el programa nuevo y asi el Hilo principal del programa sigue su curso y ejecuta la instrauccion System.Exit(0).

cerrando el programa, pero siguiendo la ejecucion del nuevo programa a instalar